# Output of aws log tail disappearing inside terraform local-exec

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, terraform

So im not sure quite what part of this is going wrong.

What am I trying to do

1. using terraform and running an ECS task during apply
2. using `terraform_data` (previously `null_resource`)
3. the script
4. start running the task
5. use `aws logs tail ... --follow &` to show the logs whilst the task runs - running in the background so that I can run
6. use `aws ecs wait tasks-stopped` to wait until the task finishes
7. kill the tail command

what's wrong

- the output of `aws logs tail ... --follow &`  isn't seen.
- all the other output of the script is shown during `terraform apply`
- if I run `aws logs tail` without `--follow` at the end, I see all the logs
- weirdly, I ran `aws logs tail ... --follow --debug &` and I see the debug output of the command (which is on `stderr`) but still not the main output
- I can run the same script just in a shell, and it works, I see all the output, but in terraform disappears

Where are the logs going?!

- is `local-exec` doing something weird?
- is `aws` cli doing something weird

```
resource "terraform_data" "run_task" {
  triggers_replace = {
    task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
  START="$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"
  TASK_ARN="$(aws ecs run-task --cluster "$CLUSTER_ID" --task-definition "$TASK_DEFINITION_ARN" --network-configuration "$TASK_NETWORK_CONFIGURATION" --launch-type FARGATE --enable-execute-command --region "$AWS_REGION" | jq -r '.tasks[].taskArn')"
  echo "Watching task: $TASK_ARN"
  LOG_STREAM_NAME="$NAME/$CONTAINER_NAME/$(echo "$TASK_ARN" | sed "s/^arn:aws:ecs:$AWS_REGION:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:task\/$CLUSTER_NAME\///")"
  echo "Tailing logs: $LOG_STREAM_NAME"
  aws logs tail "$LOG_GROUP_NAME" --log-stream-name-prefix "$LOG_STREAM_NAME" --follow --format short &
  LOGS_PID="$!"
  until aws ecs wait tasks-stopped --cluster "$CLUSTER_ID" --tasks "$TASK_ARN" --region "$AWS_REGION"; do
    echo "Watching task: $TASK_ARN"
  done
  echo "Task has stopped: $TASK_ARN"
  kill "$LOGS_PID" || true
  EOT
    interpreter = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    environment = {...}
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can't force terraform in the background, or it might create a subshell or something when you pass it the `&` at the end of the command. You might try with providing `terraform_data` a shell script with everything you have, instead of letting it perform the commands inline.

Comment: I would recommend creating a shell script that calls `terraform apply` and then runs all that stuff you have in the `local-exec` after the `terraform apply` is done. I feel like all this elaborate stuff people try to do inside `local-exec` is trying to force Terraform to do more than it was designed to do. I've done these exact ECS deployment steps before in scripts and in CI/CD pipelines and I always did it in a script than ran *after* `terraform apply` was completed, instead of inside Terraform itself.

Comment: in this case, having it inside of `terraform_data` is that other resources can depend on this, so they wait until this script has finished running to be applied, or not be applied if it crashes